# Django How to rename file upload by can change path?

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload

I want to change filename before upload. I create folder for store image which seperate by catagories of image. So, I have to set folder path for upload. This is my code for rename file and set path.

```
def path_and_rename(instance, filename,path):
    upload_to = path
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    # get filename
    if instance.pk:
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
    else:
        # set filename as random string
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
    # return the whole path to the file
    return os.path.join(upload_to, filename)
```

I upload  by this code.

```
image=models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename("path_image1"))
```

when I run it show error like this.

```
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename("path_image1"))
TypeError: path_and_rename() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'filename' and 'path'
```

I don't know how to set parameter and filename. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield) you will see that the the `upload_to` attribute is a callable.

Specifically note how user_directory_path is called: `models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)`. There are no arguments and no method call `()`.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Your function will need to be something like, so it returns a callable (please note I havent tested this):

```
def path_and_rename(path):
    def path_and_rename_func(instance, filename):
        upload_to = path
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        # get filename
        if instance.pk:
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
        else:
            # set filename as random string
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
        # return the whole path to the file
        return os.path.join(upload_to, filename)
    return path_and_rename_func


image=models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename("path_image1"))
```